# Pass parameter to GraphQL

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

How to pass parameter to GraphQL? I tried below code, but get error `Undefined name 'tenant_id'.\nTry correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.`

**GqlQuery**

```
mixin GqlQuery {
  static String getTenancyListQuery = '''
  query{
   tenancy($tenant_id: String!) {    // error in this line
    id
    invoices{
      id
      }
    }
  }
  ''';
}
```

**repo**

```
@override
  Future<List<TenancyListResponse>?> getTenancyList() async {
    try {
      final result = await _client.query(QueryOptions(
          document: gql(GqlQuery.getTenancyListQuery),
          variables: const {"tenant_id": 9, "page": 1}));

      return result.data?['tenancy']
          .map((e) => TenancyListResponse.fromJson(e))
          .cast<TenancyListResponse>()
          .toList();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Exception $e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your query and define parameters one level higher. Also your query apparently expects an `Int` and not a `String` as part of an input object `q`.

Instead of:

```
query{
  tenancy($tenant_id: String!) {
    id
    invoices{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Try:

```
query myQuery($tenant_id: Int!) {
  tenancy(q: {tenant_id: $tenant_id}) { 
    id
    invoices{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

This may seem redundant but it allows you to run multiple queries/mutations in a single request and route parameters to each one correctly.

Comment: still same error..I have edited my post

Comment: Look at the schema - what is the name of the variable that `tenancy` expects - clearly you're not using the correct name.

Comment: What schema you mean?

Comment: Oh I see it now in your graphiql- your query expects a number, not a string!

Comment: ok, but still doesn't fix my issue